# How to concat multiple tag inside a view decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper

I have a decorator in my rails view.

```
     h.content_tag(:p, class:["buttons"]) do
      h.mail_to object.email, class:"button is-small" do |button|
        h.content_tag(:span, class:["icon","is-small"]) do
          "<i class='far fa-envelope'></i>".html_safe
        end +
        h.content_tag(:span, "Mail")
      end
      h.link_to admin_participant_path(object), class:"button is-small" do |button|
        h.content_tag(:span, class:["icon","is-small"]) do
          "<i class='far fa-user'></i>".html_safe
        end +
        h.content_tag(:span, "Show")
      end
    end
```

In my view I have only the latest part rendered, so basically the show. Not the email.
If I add a '+' to contact the `mail_to` and `link_to` helpers I have an error.

How can I concat them?

Answer (score 1):

I think the right answer would be to use "capture" and "concat" Rails helpers.

Look at this article:
https://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/

It is old but should still is valid in Rails recent versions.